# Resizing focused Grid element in UWP C#

Tags: c#, event-handling, uwp, grid, resize

I have this app where I can insert images and move them around.

What I want is to be able to resize them when some Grid is in focus on Up/Down arrow on keyboard.

I have tried with adding this function into KeyDown but it does not work

```
UIElement_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
```

After this I saw some comments on net and tried with

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += UIElement_OnDownKey;
```

But I don't know how can I get through this function focused element and resize it since I end up with

```
CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs e
```

elements

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do what I intended simply by adding

```
private async void UIElement_OnDownKey(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Image myImage = GetFrontImage();
    switch(e.VirtualKey)
    {
        case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down: //Same thing for Up. 
        {
             myImage.Width = myImage.Width * 0.98;
             myImage.Height = myImage.Height * 0.98;
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

GetFrontImage() gets me image that is under the cursor of the mouse, which I set as following:

```
img.PointerEntered += setFocuse; // setFocuse function sets this image to be the one returned by GetFrontImage() function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ( even should ) use [`FocusManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.focusmanager). To use this in a simple case, whenever you click/tap on some object you just have to set direct focus on that element. Then after settings focus on that element you can use retrieve focused element and operate on it.